# Does Femme Fatale target exactly 1 ice, or all with same name?

Tags: android-netrunner

If the corp has multiple copies of the same ice, [Wall of Static](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/20131) for example, and the runner plays [Femme Fatale](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/20029) and chooses a Wall of Static for its special ability, does that mean the runner can use Femme on all Ice named "Wall of Static", or just the one specific piece of ice that they chose?

Comment: Actually, I hit approve on the pending edit that removes the social bits ("Hey" and "Thanks"), but we should also change the question title to be more descriptive ("Does Femme Fatale affect all ice of the same name as the one chosen?"), and point out that Wall of Static is just an example ice, and not really an important part of the question.

Answer (score 5):

It's just the one. When a card in Android: Netrunner is referring to multiple cards of the same name, it'll refer to them as copies, e.g. [Copycat](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/04025). There are also [other examples](https://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=x%3Acopy).

[image: Copycat card image]

Answer (score 0):

Femme Fatale targets a specific piece of ice, not ice by name, it can even target ice you don't know the name of (unrezzed) in which case how would it let you get past other copies of the same ice. If Femme allowed you to bypass all ice of the same type it would only be able to target rezzed ice (so you could know what ice you are allowed to bypass, and refer to bypassing that ice and all copies of that ice, or would allow you to name a piece of ice, allowing you to bypass all ice with that name.